# Handle error while filtering list of objects in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

Hello I'm emitting each item from the List individually in the ViewModel class to perform some validations on a string of each item which returns boolean value and I update that boolean value in each item and return List. But I'm unable to update one more parameter in List as reason which will come as `Throwable.stacktrace()`.

**In ViewModel**:

```
 fun validateList(list: List<TestModel>): Single<List<TestModel>> {
    return Observable.fromIterable(list)
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
        .map { it.jsonString }
        .map { it?.let { VerifiableObject(it) } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Json must not be null") }
        .flatMapSingle { validate() }
        .toList()
        .map {
            list.mapIndexed { index, testModel ->
                (if (it[index] != null) {
                     //Updating boolean value here
                    testModel.isVerified = it[index].toString()
                } else throw Exception("ERROR")); testModel
            }
        }
}
```

**In Fragment**:

```
viewModel. validateList(arrayList)
        .doFinally {
            showLoading(false)
        }
        .asyncToUiSingle()
        .subscribe({

            //Updating UI
            adjustCard(it)
        }, {
            it.printStackTrace()
        })
        .addTo(disposables)
```

**TestModel**:

```
 data class TestModel(
val title: String,
var isVerified: String? = null,
var reason: String? = null)
```

Here I need to insert value in `reason` field once any item gets false value with exception. Please help me if you have any idea about it.

Comment: How about not throwing that error but assigning some value to `TestModel.reason` in the `else` clause?

Comment: but error does not come in else case. It directly calls to subscribe it.printstacktrace at the time of error.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: any API call error. It does not get caught in else clause. Thats the reason. I want in else clause so I can update aerialist with dynamic error at correct index of arraylist.

Comment: Is `validate` failing? If so, how is validate not depending on the current item?

Answer (score 0):

If `validate` is causing you trouble, apply `onErrorResumeNext` to it and turn the subsequence back into the original `TestModel` item:

```kotlin
fun validateList(list: List<TestModel>): Single<List<TestModel>> {
    return Observable.fromIterable(list)
           .flatMapSingle { value ->
                validate(VerifiableObject(value.jsonString))
                .map { 
                     value.isVerified = it.toString
                     value 
                }
                .onErrorResumeNext {
                     value.reason = it.toString
                     Single.just(value)
                }
           }
           .toList()
}
```